# Aggregate an Running Sum in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a simple data set showing the number of points scored by a player.  It is plotted across a [Week Number] x-axis.  I added a Running Sum calculation, as a Line, split by Player (color).
[image: Running Sums by Week]

For each week, I would like to identify the top player, by total points achieved to-date.
For example, in Week 3, the top player was GREEN with a running total of 8 points.

I tried creating a LOD function `{FIXED [WEEK]: MAX(RunningSum)}` but it complains that I cannot aggregate an aggregate.
I tried WINDOW_MAX(), RANK(), and tried adjusting the Table Calc, Advanced, Partitioning and Addressing feature.

Is there no way to identify the MAX of a collection of running totals, by discrete [Week Number]?

This can be done fairly easily in TSQL by wrapping a query in outer queries and applying Window functions with partitions defined.

Answer (score 6):

You can absolutely just use RANK(), you just need to make sure the table calculation is being computed using Player. I imagine your `[RunningSum]` field looks something like this:

```
RUNNING_SUM(SUM([Points]))
```

Create a table calculation (let's call it `[Player Rank]`):

```
RANK([RunningSum])
```

Then we need to edit the table calculation. You can do this directly from the Calculated Field edit window (there's a blue link above the OK and Apply buttons that says something like "Default Table Calculation").

We want to compute the rank of our players, so we'll go into "Compute Using:" and select Player.

For a quick sanity check, drag `[Player Rank]` into Tooltip and check it out.